# How to convert an image to grayscale in react native?

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to manipulate an image in react native so it appears as grayscale? I want to try something like: `filter: grayscale(1)`

Thanks.

Comment: Any news? This could be a cool component.

Comment: Any updates on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 22):

Working on a previously deleted answer, this is possible by having an image, with the other image positioned absolute over the top.

The "back" image is using `tintColor`, as defined here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html, this will turn all pixels that aren't transparent into that color.

The "front" image gets an opacity added to it, which brings the "back" color forward, leaving you with a "greyscale" image

Before:

```
<React.Fragment>
   <Image source={<something>} />
</React.Fragment>
```

[image: Standard image]

After (With a backing image):

```
<React.Fragment>
   <Image source={<something>} style={{ tintColor: 'gray' }} />
   <Image source={<something>} style={{ position: 'absolute', opacity: 0.3}} />
</React.Fragment>
```

[image]

`'red'` as `tintColor`:

[image]

Comment: tintColor is *very nice*

Comment: Its a good alt. solution. we can even merge both the image tags in a single image tag. its working for me. Thank you.

Comment: It's a good alternative that might suffice for some cases, but it cannot be considered as converting image to grayscale. The colors are still very much there.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. You are just adding a grey overlay over the image, definitively not a grayscale filter.

Comment: It was a reasonable quick win in 2018, there are definitely "better" and more correct ways, but the best one for me would have been something that worked without any extra native dependencies. 

This answer is now 6 years old too, hopefully a better way to do it has come along.  react-native-color-matrix-image-filters looks good, and looks like it was available in 2018, but it would have been a native dependency to add.

Answer (score 15):

You can use my [react-native-color-matrix-image-filters](https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-color-matrix-image-filters) library:

```js
import { Image } from 'react-native';
import { Grayscale } from 'react-native-color-matrix-image-filters';

const GrayscaledImage = (imageProps) => (
    <Grayscale>
        <Image {...imageProps} />
    </Grayscale>
);
```

Comment: Looks great! Can we include it in Expo?

Comment: You can't use rncmif with Expo unless you run 'eject'.

Comment: i'm gettting `CMIFColorMatrixImageFilter was not found` on `ios`

Comment: @newbie, this happens because the module wasn't linked properly, you have to remove it from your project and link again according to the instruction from readme - https://github.com/iyegoroff/react-native-color-matrix-image-filters#installation

Comment: Hey, I'm using your library and im having an issue: I have a slider controlling the amount of contrast in my image which is wrapped in a ColorMatrix component. I can drag the slider up, and contrast goes up in the image, but when I drag the slider back down, the image contrast doesn't change even though the actual contrast value is changing. do you know how I can fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @AndyLebowitz please provide a minimal repro

Comment: dont use, getting out of memory error if we use with flatlist

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a react native package that does just that - converts to grayscale - so I've created one, but only for iOS for know, sorry. I'll add support for android soon.

https://github.com/gabrielpoliciuc/react-native-grayscale

It works with the base64 format input/output. But you can pass base64 to Image like this (please check also the example on github)

```
  <Image
    ...
    source={{ uri: base64ImageString }}
  />
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this on the fly is not supported yet. If it is a static image, you could convert it e.g. in Photoshop.

Comment: Martin, there are ways to do this in obj-c, is there a way I can call native code for this?

Comment: Yes, you can call your Obj-C code from JS. Does this guide help?
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-ios.html

Comment: Or you could implement a version of RCTImageView which converts images to grayscale:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-ios.html
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/RCTImageView.m

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import Jimp from 'jimp/browser/lib/jimp'

function GrayscaleImage(props) {
  const [base64, setBase64] = useState()
  useEffect(() => {
    ;(async () => {
      const image = await Jimp.read(props.source.uri)
      image.grayscale()
      setBase64(await image.getBase64Async(image.getMIME()))
    })()
  }, [props])

  return base64 ? <Image {...props} source={{ uri: base64 }} /> : null
}

export default GrayscaleImage
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, if possible you should [edit] your answer to include a short explanation of *how* this code block answers the question. This helps to provide context and makes your answer much more useful to future readers.