# React native expo set image grayscale

Tags: react-native, expo

how i can set my image string base64 to grayscale in react native expo

i'm try to set style but it not working

style like

```
tintColor: 'gray',
opacity: 0.3,
```

and try to use react-native-grayscale but is only iOS

[i'm want image result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z9c6.png)

Answer (score -2):

[Duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606221/how-to-convert-an-image-to-grayscale-in-react-native)

Set the opacity according to your requirements.

```html
<View>
<Image
          source={Images.Logo}
          style={{
            width: width * 0.5,
            resizeMode: "contain",
            tintColor: "gray",
          }}
        />
        <Image
          source={Images.Logo}
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            opacity: 0.1,
            width: width * 0.5,
            resizeMode: "contain",
          }}
        />
        </View>
```